# I want these boxes in a row , but boxes appear like in a column

Tags: html, css

I typed this code and i want boxes like in a row (horizontal) , but it appears like in a column(vertical).
I just want these colour boxes horizontal with spaces between them. (like top layer)

Ex- main box(grey) , and 7 boxes in the top ( with margins & paddings)

Like this : 4 color Boxes in a bigger grey color box.

I used "div" tag , but it only work for first one only
How could i align those boxes and have spaces between them ?
Thanks in advance.

```css
.header_box {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: -webkit-box;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  background: white;
}

.box2 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box3 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box4 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box5 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box6 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box7 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.middle_box {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display -webkit-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box0 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box11 {
  background: blue;
}

.box12 {
  background: yellow;
}

.box13 {
  background: red;
}

.box14 {
  background: green;
}

.circle1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.circle3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  background-color: gold;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  /* 100px of height + 10px of         border */
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.img-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div class="header_box">
      <div class="box box1" align="center">
        logo
      </div>
      <div class="box box6" align="center">

      </div>
      <div class="box box7" align="center">

      </div>
      <div class="box box2" align="center">
        TEXT 01
      </div>
      <div class="box box3" align="center">
        TEXT 02
      </div>
      <div class="box box4" align="center">
        TEXT 03
      </div>
      <div class="box box5" align="center">
        TEXT 04
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Pictures\sample3.png" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="middle_box">
      <div class="box0 box11">
      </div>
      <div class="box02 box12">
      </div>
      <div class="box0 box13">
      </div>
      <div class="box0 box14">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle1">
    </div>
    <div class="circle2">
    </div>
    <div class="circle3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="img-circle" src="C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Downloads\sunsetmypht.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because you forgot a colon in the `display` directive.

You have:

```
display -webkit-box;
```

Use:

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

That being said, look into `flex` and `flex-direction` (I usually use [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

To get the circles on a horizontal row you need to wrap them in a `div` which has the same `display` rule as the boxes (for example by assigning the `middle_box` class to the `div`).

Comment: thanks.  What about circles in my page ? i will mark your answer as solution

Comment: do circles also need  something like :         display: -webkit-box;   ?

Comment: what sould i do to get those circles also horizontal ?